# automatic select Today last created file and sent email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make an automatic email script which is automatically attached a certain file in the given folder and email the file.

I have tried this file where I manually attach the file in the email script.I don't want to edit the code, rename the file every time sent an email. For automatic email sent I'm using **yagmail** module in python.
[Note:Using Windows System]

Inside of myproject/Attendance directory, there are four files. Here are the file name and lists.

```
myproject\Attendance\Attendance_2019-08-22_00-38-17.csv
myproject\Attendance\Attendance_2019-08-24_13-34-43.csv
myproject\Attendance\Attendance_2019-08-24_14-11-44.csv
myproject\Attendance\Attendance_2019-08-24_14-44-53.csv
```

**Code snippet**

```py
import yagmail

receiver = "mygmail@gmail.com"  # receiver email address
body = "Attendence File"  # email body
filename = "Attendance\Attendance_2019-08-24_13-34-43.csv"  # attach the file

# mail information
yag = yagmail.SMTP("mygmial@gmail.com", "mypassword")

# sent the mail
yag.send(
    to=receiver,
    subject="Attendance Report",  # email subject
    contents=body,  # email body
    attachments=filename,  # file attached
)
```

I want to select the last created attendance file and auto attached in the email. For example, here in **Attendance** directory the last file was created named *"Attendance_2019-08-24_14-44-53.csv"*. This file will be selected and attached in the email.

Thanks, Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` will get you all the file names in the directory.  Depending on the semantics of "last created", you can do either of these:

1. Sort the file names: it appears that they're of a regular format.  The first one in the collating sequence is the most recent date.
2. Use the `os` command capabilities to inquire of the *actual* creation date of each file.  Keep the latest creation date and file name.

Note that it can be even more direct: issue a system command to list the files in order of age, and simply take the last file from the returned list.  For UNIX (including Linux), this would be `ls -ltr Attendance*`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :
If you have Unix filesystem, you use '`ls -lrt '` do grep with timestamp or use with `awk` command to get last file generated. 
Then you can attach your file.

Option 2 :
Take a variable of previous file name and take recent generated file name and do comparison then attach to email